# Swift property loaded in memory before initialisation is called

Tags: swift

In my app it looks like the property is loaded in memory before it's even called. Either there's something wrong with my understanding, or there's something I've overlooked. To illustrate that I've put a breakpoint soon after signIn is tapped as you can see on the image (line 226):

[image]

I'm expecting to initialise a property `let user = User()` on line 230. So I have no idea how could user be already loaded in memory, as seen on the bottom left of the attached image.

Why does this happen?
Is this some kind of code optimisation that happens under the hood?

I can confirm that `user` has not been loaded / initialised prior to that (it's not a class property). Additionally I can confirm that commenting out line 230 and below results in user not being loaded, so it looks that line 230 is the cause for user being loaded. But the strange thing is that this happens before it's called, as I've paused the execution on line 226 with a breakpoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's important to be able to read the variables list. *All local variables are always shown*, even if they have not been initialized yet, because the *storage* has already been set aside for them. Before initialization, therefore, the *variable* is shown, but its *value* may be bogus. My guess is that the value *is* bogus. It *says* it's a User because that is its type, but at the time you are looking, it is pointing at garbage, and you should ignore it. After the execution path passes thru the initialization, the value will change and will be the real value.

(However, if this is a Release build, then there might indeed be optimization of some sort, because this is a *constant* whose value does not depend upon preceding code, so it can be allocated at any time. But you should not be debugging a Release build.)

Answer (score 2):

It hasn't been loaded into memory.  The debugger sees the variable in scope and displays it but the number it's showing is whatever is lying around in memory.  If you step past your `let user...` statement, you should see the value of the variable change to something more like the other object addresses in your picture.